# Implement custom view in chatting app

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am working on a chatting app. I want to show a custom view at the bottom just like Facebook Messenger. Facebook Messenger have a custom view at the bottom which comes in chatting screen. This view is of exact height as that of virtual keyboard. This custom view shows camera, stickers, recording option and much more. How can I implement this kind of view in my app?

The part in the red box in the first image is the view I want to show which will come in the place of keyboard. This custom view can be just any Layout. I may show camera, pictures, musics, videos, files, emoji or sticker here. Please help me out.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, you implement it just like you would implement any other layout and I very much doubt that this is a custom view in the first place.

Comment: Oh and this "custom view"  does not have the same height as the keyboard, just a very similar one. Try a few different keyboards and you will see that the height of the keyboard is always different but the "custom view" stays the same.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Is it just a normal view and all I have to do is hide and show it? And yeah, how can I show an emoji keyboard of my own?

Comment: @Nitesh, Im trying to do the same thing, so if you find an answer or tutorial on this, please let me know